# Change entire column format - phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql

In a project I am working on, I have a column in my database named `Amount`. This is a money format, but there is no need for it to have a dollar sign in front.

I would like every value that is entered in here to be this format:

`123456 -> 123,456.00`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

No, the stored value should not be formatted, it should be stored as a plain number, otherwise you can't do any arithmetic calculations.

When the number is displayed, that's when you format its appearance either in the application layer (that's the preferred approach) or you can use MySQL's own [format()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_format) function in the select statement to achieve this:

```
select format(amount) from your_table
```

Comment: Thanks, you've helped.

Comment: Is there a way to format the value in a PHP table in a while loop?

Comment: Yep, there is. If you did a quick google search on php format number, then you would now how.